# Use Tucky UrlRewriteFilter to hide .jsp at the end of urls

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I would like to simple hide the .jsp file extension at the end of all my urls for my Java web app. I've already gotten Tucky UrlRewriteFilter integrated using Maven, but I cannot figure out the magic rule to do what I need.

For example:

> example.com/webapp/home --> example.com/webapp/home.jsp
>
> example.com/home --> example.com/home.jsp
>
> example.com/blah --> example.com/blah.jsp

Does anyone know the trick? I've googled, read the docs, and tried several rules without luck. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<rule>
  <from>^/?([a-z]+)$</from>
  <to type="forward">/$1.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

You canl additional make **redirect** from example.com/home.jsp to the example.com/home

Answer (score -1):

```
<rule>
  <from>^/bookmark-new$</from>
  <to>/bookmark-new.jsp</to>
</rule>
```